# Get files inside folder

Tags: java

I am trying to read the content of the folder of my Java EE Spring application, but it always return me `null`. The folder I want is under `src/main/resources` folder and it`s called `context`. I try doing it this way :

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/context")
```

But it always return me `null` for file.

Comment: file can only be a existing file and not a directory. 10 secs of google and i found this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#listdir

Comment: Directory should not be a problem for the `java.io.File` object. In fact, even if the file or folder does not exist, file` will get assigned a valid non-null object.

Comment: i would suggest, get current folder path using something like: System.getProperty("user.dir"); and then append your path of the folder to the path return by this getProperty method.

Comment: `src/main/resources` implies that you're using Maven to build your application, and that we're actually talking about a folder that is a project resources. To list its content, refer to the linked question -- you can't use the `File` approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following:

```
    File file = new File("src/main/resources/context");
    String[] list = file.list(); // returns an array of all file names in the context folder.
```

OR

```
    File file = new File("src/main/resources/context");
    File[] listFiles = file.listFiles(); // returns an array of all "file objects" for all files in the context folder.
```

Hope this helps!